# Is it possible to disable Exceptions and RTTI in Boost libraries?

Tags: c++, boost, android-ndk

I develop some native libraries for Android and use Boost libraries - just headers-based ones. The problem I am facing is that when I try to link some of my native libraries against some system library the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown. It is due to different C++ runtimes as stated in the NDK documentation:

> You can only select a single C++ runtime that all your code will
>   depend on. It is not possible to mix shared libraries compiled against
>   different C++ runtimes.

System libraries do not use RTTI and Exceptions, but my libraries use it implicitly. 
I know there are macros `BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE` and `BOOST_NO_RTTI`, but I am not able to make it working. I tried to set them as compiler flags and in the config.hpp as well, but with no luck – still getting many errors like

```
cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
```

How can I disable these features in Boost, is it even possible?

Comment: Did you get that error when trying to compile Boost? Or when trying to compile your own code?

Comment: When trying to compile my own code.

Comment: BTW, your question has no sense; I wrote I use only headers..., mainly circular_buffer.hpp, signal.hpp and shared_ptr.hpp

Comment: My question is absolutely and totally general and simple question whether is it possible to disable RTTI and Exceptions in Boost libraries or not. If so, then how? That’s all. All other sentences are only a rationale why I am trying to do so. I defined preprocessor macros for GCC just the way like all other macros: `-DBOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE` and `-DBOOST_NO_RTTI`. I also defined `-DBOOST_USER_CONFIG` and set these macros in the user config header. It doesn't work - RTTI and Exceptions are still enabled. I simply don’t know how I can be more specific.

Comment: Boost is not perfect, you know. Have you checked the source code, at the flagged uses of `typeid`, to see if that code is wrapped in a `#ifndef BOOST_NO_RTTI`? Or maybe another macro? It could be a simple omission on the developer's part, as I would imagine disabling rtti isn't the most common thing, and may never have been reported as a bug. If there are flags to disable RTTI and exceptions, then if they don't work, it's a bug in Boost.

Comment: I was Googling a lot and it seems it is not possible. I have given up and rewriting my code. I have used Boost for years in desktop development and didn’t anticipate any problems on Android – my fault. It is simply too much robust and not suitable for embedded development...; at least if you need to link with system libraries, it works fine otherwise.

Comment: @vitakot - You do realize that if the only info you provide is that you have some unspecified linker error, that the best answer you are going to get is, "Sucks to be you, hope you figure it out." It sounds like you already have your general answer, but are running into specific problems, yet you aren't providing the specific error messages or specific, reproducible steps. That said, you mentioned you are using header only libraries, but that you are also using boost signals (not signals2). Signals is compiled, or was last time I checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "maybe".
Some boost libraries will work with exceptions disabled - some will not.
Same for RTTI.

I suggest you check the documentation for the particular boost libraries that you are interested in.

For example, Boost.Array will work with exceptions disabled, but Boost.Format will not.

If you are getting messages like `cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti`, that will probably be while compiling some part of Boost that requires RTTI. Where the error occurs will tell you which library (usually).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are probably right. This message is related to boost signals library, it uses also `boost bind` which implies using `boost any` and this functionality is probably not possible without rtti enabled... Actually Boost should set itself according to the compilers settings, so I believe it is not necessary to define `BOOST_NO_RTTI` etc. explicitly.